# Facebook : List of all pages liked by

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am new to Facebook's Graph API  and FQL. I want small information about the same.
I want to get List of all pages liked by any particular user.

I have used Graph API just to allow user to get logged in with their Facebook ID and Can access their wall but don't know much about rest of the this.

I searched on Google for same but got information about list of pages that user administrate that I don't want, I want full list which is like by them.

Answer (score 0):

It's a connection property of the User object.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#likes

Comment: how to handle the result in javascript SDK